# laravel parameterized routes not working with ajax/$http

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have below route:

```
   Route::get('albums/{id}','Frontend\ProfileController@albumDetail');
```

All the ajax calls under this route become something like below:

http://localhost/abc/public/album/profile/get-notes

Where as in my ajax call I am trying to access below route:

```
Route::post('profile/get-notes','Frontend\ProfileController@getNotes');
```

Code I have written for ajax:

```
 $http.post('profile/get-notes',note_data).success(function(response){
        $scope.notes = response.notes;
    });
```

I don't know why my system is adding 'album to my ajax call' in case of parameterized routes, otherwise working fine. And therefore getting 404 error as route for this

"http://localhost/abc/public/album/profile/get-notes" does not exist.

Comment: your details are not enough, Can you explain little more.... also tell that are you getting any error ?

Comment: Try to add `/` in front of uri: `/profile/get-notes`

Comment: @FilipKoblański it didn't help. Adding '/' in routes.php has no effect, adding '/' in $http request in angular.js omits public from the url and it becomes : "http/localhost/abc/profile/get-notes".

Comment: @Qazi I updated my question. Thanks.

Comment: Just try to add static path in ajax, see where it sends the requests.. another thing in your this route `Route::get('albums/{id}','Frontend\ProfileController@album-detail');` how you started this method `album-detail` I mean with dash(-) instead underscore?

Comment: @Qazi I have added public path of my project in front of my $http url "/abc/public/" i.e url: public_path+'/profile/get-notes' and now its working.

Comment: its mean, your routes.php is ok, you have to handle this at AJAX end, better to create Virtual Host and then try it

Comment: Ok @Qazi thank you. Saved my day!